# Converting binary code to DNA code

Tags: python

I am trying to write a python program for converting binary code to DNA code using the following data:

`A = 00, B = 10 , C = 01, D = 11`.

We input a **8 digit binary code** and the program converts it to a **4 letter dna code** using this data. What could the code for this program be?

Comment: please provide more details and show us what you've tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could loop over that input in steps of two, detect the binary word and add the corresponding nucleic acid to the output.

```
inputStr = '00011011' # ABCD
outputStr = ''

for start in range(0, len(inputStr), 2):
    word = inputStr[start:start+2]
    if word == '00': outputStr += 'A'
    elif word == '01': outputStr += 'B'
    elif word == '10': outputStr += 'C'
    elif word == '11': outputStr += 'D'
```

Comment: without the if/elif:  
  
`inputstr = "00100111" 
   
dnaMap = {'00': 'A', '10': 'B', '01': 'C', '11': 'D'}  
out = [dnaMap[inputstr[i:i + 2]] for i in range(0, len(inputstr), 2)]`